# The Selected data from dropdownlist don't appear in alert message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Display the selected data in alert when the selected data in dropdown list (month) is already selected or you have selected a new row from the dropdown list (month).

This occur when you click on the button 'Test'.

Problem:
The data doesn't appear in alert in relation to pre-selection or you have selected a new value from the dropdown list

What is needed to be changed in the source code in order to achieve the goal?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xjfetj?file=src/index.js

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 'Jan' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Feb' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Mars' },
  { value: 4, label: 'April' },
  { value: 5, label: 'May' },
  { value: 6, label: 'June' },
  { value: 7, label: 'July' },
  { value: 8, label: 'August' },
  { value: 9, label: 'Sept' },
  { value: 10, label: 'Oct' },
  { value: 11, label: 'Nov' },
  { value: 12, label: 'Dec' }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      items: [
        {
          firstName: 'Josef',
          lastName: 'Anderson',
          key: 'josef.anderson',
          startYear: 2021,
          startMonth: 2
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Jim',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'jim.west',
          startYear: 2020,
          startMonth: 3
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Joe',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'joe.west',
          startYear: 1998,
          startMonth: 10
        }
      ],
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementById('test').value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map(item => {
              const { firstName, lastName, key } = item;

              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{firstName}</td>
                  <td>{lastName}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(item)}>
                      Open Modal
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
          {openItem !== null && (
            <Modal className="confirmation-modal" isOpen={true}>
              First Name:
              <br />
              <input
                type="text"
                id="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                value={openItem.firstName}
                onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                id="lastName"
                name="lastName"
                value={openItem.lastName}
                onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
              />
              <Select
                defaultValue={options.filter(
                  option => option.value === openItem.startMonth
                )}
                name="startMonth"
                id="test"
                options={options}
              />
              <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Test</button>
            </Modal>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Modal.setAppElement(document.getElementById('root'));
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay--after-open {
  opacity: 1;

  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content {
  position: absolute;

  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content--after-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirmation-modal button:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Select uses its own elements in select, Its not like general HTML select that you can access by this ID since the ID you passed goes to the parent element of the input element, So you get undefined there

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8schc7?file=src/index.js

You can use getElementByName to access that value in this specific way

```
alert(
  JSON.stringify({
    test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
  })
);
```

But, You wouldn't want to access values in this way by accessing directly from the dom. You should make select a controlled input and store the value in a state, and then access it. another option could be that you can use onChange to store the value of the select, if you don't really want to use controlled input.